# Changing password asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Is there a quick way to verify is user exists and based on existence of user name get user id?

(i.e. the user only has the user name and the adds it to change their password)?

I would think something like this... `String userId = User.Identity.GetUserId(userName);`

I am looking for a quick way for local users to change their password if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.Identity.GetUserId()` will return the id of current logged in user.
From `UserManager` you can get any user from their username like this

```
var user = UserManager.FindByName("the username here");
```

then you can change password from `UserManager` again

```
UserManager.ChangePassword(user.Id, "OldPassword", "NewPassword");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have it, thanks

```
        var user = UserManager.FindByName(userName);
        String userId = user.Id;
```