# How to send email to registered user (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-identity

My problem is this one, I have users that are registered in a basic MVC 5 application, when they register they provide email address and a username.
In the application userA can see what userB created (ie a product or whatever), what I want to do is that for userA to "contact" userB by clicking on a button, however userA will not see the email address of userB, the application will send the mail on its behalf (sendgrid).

My pain points are :

1 - once userA click the button, a small issue is how open a new page where he can type its subject and message without loosing the username of userB

2 - how can I retrieve the email address of userB ? I can't find a way to retrieve the email address of the user

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Assuming I understood, you could assign some "id" representing UserB as the "data" of the button (`value`, `data-`, `id`, etc), process it on "submit"  (query based on "id", and send email)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a method for sending email via SendGrid:

```
public static string SendEmail(string SendTo, string MessageBody, string subject)
    {
        try
        {
            string FromEmail = "your app's email";

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = (new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(FromEmail.Trim()));
            mailMessage.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(SendTo.Trim()));

            mailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Body = MessageBody.Trim();

            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            return ("Message Sent");
        }
        catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException smtpExc)
        {
            //Log error information on which email failed.
            return ("SMTP Error");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log general errors
            return ("Error");
        }
    }
```

To keep Username to another page just pass the information to the controller.`@Html.ActionLink("Send Email", "Controller Name", new { username = "userB" })`

```
public virtual ActionResult SendMessage(string username)
{
    ViewBag.usename = username;
    return View();
}
```

To get the email from a user name use: [from the answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640110/changing-password-asp-net-identity)

```
var user = UserManager.FindByName("the username here");
var email = user.email;
```

Comment: Thank you @Cook Data ! I nearly got it working, the only part that I can't figure out is how to have `UserManager.FindByName` working, how can I get working, by default it gives me `Using the generic type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser,TKey>' requires 2 type arguments` error, I tried several things but I am never able to have `UserManager.FindByName`. Thank you in advance for your help on this last piece !

Comment: ok I finally found it ! I added 
`var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));` Thank you again !