# Change Password in UserManager(Asp.Identity) c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, usermanager

Please suggest best practice to update new password in Database through UserManager in Asp.Identity

Currently I am using below approach to update password. Is this enough or I want to use different approach?

```
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
String userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();//"<YourLogicAssignsRequestedUserId>";
String newPassword = "test@123"; //"<PasswordAsTypedByUser>";
String hashedNewPassword = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(newPassword);
ApplicationUser cUser = await store.FindByIdAsync(userId);
**await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(cUser, hashedNewPassword);
await store.UpdateAsync(cUser);**
```

Comment: do you know the old password? or you want an admin to change password for other users?

Comment: Yes I will get the old password from user and need to check it through usermanager.

Comment: then you can use ChangePassword(userId, "OldPassword", "NewPassword") method, more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640110/changing-password-asp-net-identity/30641090#30641090)

Comment: Thank you so much friend